# Free, simple, configurable SOCKS5 server

Tags: proxy, python, socks-proxy, socks, socks5

I've been looking (for the past 6-7 hours) for a fast, free and configurable SOCKS5 server. I haven't found anything that matches my needs. They are either too complicated, too bare-bones or simply buggy as hell.

This is (all) I need:

- I want it to run on Linux (and also OS X, preferably)
- I want it to listen on localhost:8888
- When my app *(say `wget..` or `curl --socks5=localhost:8888`)* requests `http://www.google.com/search?q=asd` *(or any other url - both http and https)*, I want it to fetch the page not from google's servers, but from `http://localhost:4444/cached?uri=http://www.google.com/search%3Fq%3Dasd`.
- Nothing more!

I don't need caching, or anything else. I just want a SOCKS5 server, running locally, which redirects all queries to my own (local) server.

It could be written in C, C++, Python, PHP, Perl, Node.js or any other language. I don't care, as long as it supports my (very limited) needs, or I can easily change the source to make it so.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

use ssh! ssh -D 8888 server-ip

then all it takes is connecting to it through that port number!

also it should be noted unless your client is configured not to the shell could eventually time out.. it is worth running a keep alive script.

```
#!/bin/sh
while[1]; do echo "keep alive"; sleep 10; done;
```

should suffice

Comment: downvote with no reason why? nice ssh is indeed a socks proxy